# Меняем значение переменной после обновления страницы

Tags: php, случайные-числа, переменные

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста, как после каждого обновления страницы записывать разные значения в переменную?

**Например есть значения:**

- Вася
- Петя
- Паша

*обновляем страницу и записываем в переменную одно из значений (рандомно)*

`$znachenie = 'Петя';`

*обновляем снова и получаем опять рандомно значение*

`$znachenie = 'Вася';`

Comment: @СергейМишин а зачем?

Comment: @Ипатьев не так условие прочитал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то вот так:

```php
<?php
$names = array("Петя", "Вася", "Паша");
$znachenie = $names[ rand(0, count( $names ) -1) ];
echo $znachenie."\n";
```

Comment: вместо `rand(0, count( $names ) -1)` в РНР есть специальная функция `array_rand($names)`

Comment: Простите великодушно. Не помню все функции `PHP` наизусть :)

Comment: Сделал как написал Ипатьев и получил то что нужно. Благодарю господа!

Comment: И тут минусанули репу!!!!!!!! Вы чё а?